# Line break in XMLView UI5

Tags: sapui5

How can I set a line break between two controls?

[image]
I want to display one by one in vertical manner.

Comment: In case anyone wanted to add a "line break" **within text**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65767922/5846045

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a flex box control: either [`<VBox>`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.VBox) or [`<HBox>`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.HBox).

```xml
<VBox xmlns="sap.m" wrap="Wrap" renderType="Bare">
  <!-- ... -->
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really use linebreaks but layout controls.

If you want to have an element below another element, put both of them in a vertical layout.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout/samples

```
<l:VerticalLayout>
    <Input placeholder="UserID" />
    <Input placeholder="Password" type="Password" />
</l:VerticalLayout>
```

Don't forget to include the namespace: `xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"`

You can also nest different layouts: Outer layout is vertical, and each row of the vertical layout can be a horizontal layout where items are placed next to each other.

---

**Edit:** This also works in IE9. `VBox` unfortunately does not work in IE9.